# make describe-function link to org file for "tangled" lisp functions

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a lot of my emacs configuration in an org babel file, which I load with `org-babel-load-file`. My configuration is in `my-emacs-config.org`.

When I use `describe-function` for one of the functions I define there, it links to the tangled `.el` file, but I'd like it to link to my org file.

For example:

```
my-function is a Lisp function in ‘../my-emacs-config.el’.

(my-function)

Blah blah documentation for my function here.

[back]
```

The `../my-emacs-config.el` is a link. But I want that to link to `../my-emacs-config.org` -- the original org source file.

Note that the manual has a bit on the `:comments link` header argument ([see here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html)) but that just seems to put an org-mode style link at the top of the output `.el` file. I want something that advises `describe-function` or somehow gives me a link to the org source file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the `.org` files and the corresponding tangled `.el` files in the same directory? If so, you can  get the `.el` file and interject a transformation to the corresponding `.org` file, perhaps by redefining `find-list-object-file-name` which is the function used by `describe-function` to get the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NickD and the magic of [`:filter-return` advice](https://scripter.co/emacs-lisp-advice-combinators/#advice-combinators--filter-return), this turns out to be super simple: we write a function that akes the file name that `find-lisp-object-file-name` returns, and for those that came from our literate org files, change the `.el` to `.org`.

For my setup, here's all I need to do:

```
(defun filter-find-lisp-object-file-name (fn)
  "If the output of `find-lisp-object-file-name' is config.el,
change that to config.org; otherwise, this is the identity
 function."
  (if (string= fn "/home/dan/.emacs.d/my-emacs-config.el")
      "/home/dan/.emacs.d/my-emacs-config.org"
      fn))

(advice-add 'find-lisp-object-file-name :filter-return #'filter-find-lisp-object-file-name)
```

The `filter-return` advice function is very simple: it just needs some logic to identify the `.el` files that come from my literate `.org` files, and to change those appropriately. In my case, there's only one, so the logic is very simple, but it would be straightforward to do some parsing of the path or other logic. For anything *not* from my configuration, the filter just passes through the file name.